# how to print another webpage with pass value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

---

I want to print a report or other web pages by passing a value without open it, can someone help me, how do that?this example my code

```
   <td><a href="print.php?id_card=<?php echo $row['id_card']; ?>" onClick="?">print</a> </td>
```

Comment: what does your print.php do?

Comment: this is a link to the page `print.php?id_card=XX`. You can make it open in new tab, inside a popup or make it render what it has inside without getting opened by calling it within an ajax request. but still depends on what print.php does

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need something like this?

```
<td><a href="#" onclick="javascript: openP(<?php echo $row['id_card']; ?>);">print</a> </td>
```

Javascript function

```
   <script>
function openP(id)
{
    var url = "filename.php?id_card="+id;
    window.open(url, "ID Card", "width=800, height=300, left=200, top=100");
}
</script>
```

This would open a popup and will load `filename.php` with `id_card` as accessible via `$_GET['id_card']`

Comment: after i try,nothing happened, the popup does not appear

Comment: @RyanIrfandi Upload it somewhere to let me have a closer look.

Comment: Your comment proves why this couldn't have worked for you. How am I going to see a file which is hosted on your localhost mate?